# Does Using get parameters gives correct answer all the time?

Tags: php

Should I use get parameters or should I query again when moving from one page to other **If the parameters change dynamically** from one page to other?

Take an example.
I have two pages **`www.example.com`** and **`www.example.com?a=`** .
In the second page a value changes depending on user choice.'a' is a field in database say quantity of books in online book store

In the first page say `a=2` at some point of time and at this point of time first user moves to second page and stays there for some point of time.In the mean time second user visits the second page and the a value changes to say `a=0`. And now for the first user will the a value be 2 got from the get parameter or 0.

My question is if we use get parameters `a` value **may be wrong**.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include('connection.php');
  $quant=isset($_GET['quant'])?$_GET['quant']:NULL;
  $cod=isset($_GET['cod'])?$_GET['cod']:NULL;
  if($cod!=NULL){
 ?>
<form name="select" action="block.php" method="get">
          <p>Enter number of books you want to block</p>  <br/>
          <input type="textbox" name="quant"><br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="cod" value="<?php echo "$cod"; ?>">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
<?php
}
else{
 $qry="select * from books where category='ncert' and quantity>0  ";
      $books=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
      $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($books);

      if($numrows>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($books)){
          $quantity=$row['quantity'];
          echo "$quantity";
          ?>
          <a href="example.php?<?php echo "$cod";?> example </a>
          <?php 
        }
      }
   }
 ?>
```

**Block.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');
$quant1=isset($_GET['quant'])?$_GET['quant']:NULL;
$cod1=isset($_GET['cod'])?$_GET['cod']:NULL;
$qry="select * from books where code='$cod1' ";
$quantity=$row['quantity'];// **This is the quantity I am talking about**
if($quantity>=$quant1&&$quant1>0){
  // user buys quant1 amount of books 
}
?>
```

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: For every request to your website, a new instance of the system is executed, which does not share the $_GET parameters among them. Each request has it's own array

Comment: @Nadir 'a' is a field in database if a gets changed by second user then database may not have correct value(got from get parameter) when used by first user

Comment: So, if it is a problem that users share the same column in the database, why don't you just use a different row for each user? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is common field say quantity of books in online book shopping system which cannot be different for different users

Comment: The database will perform the operations atomically, so when a user reads the database, it will get the correct value in that momment. That means if the user1 thinks theres 1 book left when there are 0, when he try to buy it you will read the database and you will see there are no more books, so you just display user1 an alert that says that there are no more books

Comment: @Nadir there's no guarantee that the entire transaction is atomic. Two users could both read the same data, modify it and both write to the same field.

Comment: So does get parameter changes from 1 to 0 when he try to buy it?

Comment: @user6181297 Of course not, the parameter will be whatever you told the webpage it should be when the page was rendered. Someone may change the value and the first page has a stale value. That's a race condition. We can only help if you come up with a good example of your problem. That is, your question is not as useful without code you've used and any problems you have encountered. Typically, the solution is to add a `lastModifiedDate` to your fields, if the current `lastModifiedDate` is different than the one you are submitting, you have a race condition where you have to deny a transaction

Comment: @JuanMendes Not multiple operations, I meant sinlge operations. Since you have to read and update, you can build an update statement that only updates the field if it is greater than 0. The return value will tell you if the row was updated (user1 bought the book) or it the row wasnt affected (when user1 tried to update, the column value wasnt greater than 0, so he wasnt able). You could also lock the tables, but I dont think it is necessary

Comment: so instead of using get parameter retrieving it from database field works?

Comment: If get parameter doesnot change then it shows wrong value so should I use query again on other page to get quantity

Comment: @Juan Mendes The `lastModifiedDate` will always be different from submitting date because time changes before he submits

Comment: @user6181297 Even if you retrieve it from the db, two users could both still read a value, modify it then change it. It's less likely because the time between the read and write is shorter, but you should still be careful and have some strategy to prevent concurrent modifications as I explained in my comments

Comment: Getting the `total` from the client (the GET variable) is definitely a bad idea. The simplistic answer is, yes, always read it from the db.

Comment: It is bad idea only for changing values right?

Comment: @user6181297 `lastModifiedDate` is not the current time. It's the time that the last modification was applied. If you're not going to modify the value ever, yes, then it's not a problem. The easiest way to visualize the problem is: Client A reads your balance ($500), makes a 100 witdhrawal and sets the balance to $400. Client B reads the balance before Client A sets the balance to $400. Client B makes a deposit of $100 and sets the balance to $600. The bank won't be happy with the software.

Comment: we have to maintain lastmodifiedDate for each row and a separate variable whcih is updated to latest modified time and compare those. Am I right? And race condition is implemented this way?